# Webservice suggestion which can call java method from android other then axis 2?

Tags: java, android, web-services, apache-axis

I had use an `axis2` for creating the `java web service` which call my java application method from android,

it works very well with the simple method which not using any `external jar` in java program but problems occurs when i want to call java program's method from android which using some external jar and also some resource file on run time.

Which gives the error of `resources can't locate`. i had posted a question about this problem in

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436173/webservice-giving-error-like-cant-locate-resources-when-using-another-file-with
```

so what i am trying to do is now is there any other facility like axis2 which i can implement.

i have seen some references by goggling but its not clear the things and also very out of sequence so any tutorial with the kind of axis2 facility to create web service ?

Comment: In theory, you should be able to consume any web service you like, the actual implementation of the web service is something you shouldn't be concerned about. What are you trying to achieve? You could set up mocked SOAP services in SOAP-UI and call those if you just want to prove it works?

Comment: thanks for reply,i m new bee in this so i didn't understand what u said.let me explain you what i want.that some how from android code i want to call my java application which resides on server and execute that application on server and just give output as a reply to android device as simple text.when i try to run my java application on server manually its going well but whenever i tried to call that same thing from webservice its givng me error of resource file which it cant be located

Comment: Is your web service a SOAP service? I'd suggest that you download and setup SOAP UI, then create some tests that invoke your web service. Once this works, you'd be sure the service is OK and then its just a case of making the android app consume that service (which I'd recommend using KSoap). Sounds like your service is broken, you need to fix that before you worry about an android client.

Comment: ya my service is a SOAP service..can u suggest me any tutorial about SOAP UI..i will Definitely find it by my own but if u have any reference then i will follow that link.Thanks for quick reply